# How to display only one window in my macOS app?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I know that there's a quick hack for this, that basically does:

```
var body: some Scene {

    WindowGroup
    {
        ContentView()            
    }
    .commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {
            //New window command
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

but it simply removes the "New Window" menu, which I don't want to do.

My goal is let only one window to be displayed. So I'm assuming the skeleton should be this:

```
@Environment(\.openWindow) var openWindow

var body: some Scene {

    WindowGroup
    {
        ContentView()            
    }
    .commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.newItem) {

            Button(action: {
                //New window

                //openWindow(id: .self)
                
            }) { Text("New Window")}
                .keyboardShortcut("N", modifiers: [.command])
        }
    }
}
```

But how to:

1. Display a new window.
2. See if it is already displayed and in that case do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use no `WindowGroup` at all:

```
@main
struct SO_mac_TestsApp: App {
        
    var body: some Scene {

        Window("My only Window", id: "myWindow") {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

But be aware that closing this window quits the app.

Answer (score 2):

For a single window app, write your `App` like this:

**For macOS 13+:**

The `Window` scene was introduced for macOS 13

```
@main
struct myApp: App {
    Window() {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**For macOS 11+**

In earlier versions you need restrict event handling of the `WindowGroup` scene

```
@main
struct myApp: App {
     WindowGroup {
         ContentView()
             .handlesExternalEvents(preferring: ["*"], allowing: ["*"])            
     }
     .commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem, addition: { })
     }
}
```

Comment: Any way to combine the code to support macOS 12 and 13? I wasn't able to do that via #if available...